# Does the Higgs Boson exert gravity?

Tags: gravity

The Higgs boson is considered to have mass. Would a field of Higgs bosons, W bosons, etc. give off a gravitational field for the duration of their existence?

Comment: You might be interested in [this post about the Higgs](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33203).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantum size of elementary particles is in conflict with the classical notion of "generating a gravitational field". The correct statement is that these bosons, as well as all other particles (even massless ones), do interact with the hypothesized massless spin two particle we call the graviton, through three or four point vertices.

Comment: So, assuming there were a method to "mass produce" (pun intended) bosons on a macroscopic scale, would that be a viable method of creating artificial gravity?

Comment: due to energy conservation in all known physical processes, there is no such thing as "artificial gravity"

Comment: What do you mean by quantum size?